# About a basis in a target space of a bilinear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be linear spaces and $T: X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ be a bilinear mapping such that for some base $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ in $X$ and some base $(f_j)_{j\in J}$ in $Y$ the sequence  $(T(e_i, f_j))_{i \in I, j \in J})$ is a basis in $Z$.

Let now $(e'_i)_{i\in I}$ , $(f'_j)_{j\in J}$ be other bases of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.
Is then $(T(e'_i, f'_j))_{i \in I, j \in J})$  a basis in $Z$?

Comment: Are your spaces infinite dimensional ?

Comment: I'm interested mainly the case when all the spaces have finite dimensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes (actually it is also yes for free modules).

Let $X\otimes Y$ be the tensor product of $X$ and $Y$. The fact that $(e_i)_I$ is a basis of $X$ and $(f_j)$ is a basis of $Y$ implies that the family $(e_i\otimes f_j)$ is a basis of $X\otimes Y$ and similarly with $(e'_i)$ and $(f'_j)$.

Now, $T$ factors as a linear application from $X\otimes Y$ to $Z$. If it sends the basis $(e_i\otimes f_j)$ to a basis in $Z$, then it is bijective, so that it sends any basis of $X\otimes Y$ to a basis of $Z$. In particular, the family $T(e_i'\otimes f_j')$ is a basis of $Z$.

Now, if you don't like tensor products or are not familiar with them, you can easily check that the family $T(e_i',f_j')$ is a generating family, writing explicitely a decomposition of the basis $(e'_i)$ in the basis $(e_i)$ and similarly with $f'_j$ and $f_j$. This settles the finite dimensional case.